# Differential Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I can't solve this exercise my professor gave me.. is there anyone who is able to?

Study:

(P) $\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=-x+xy\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-2y-x^{2}
\end{cases}$

a) Demonstrate that the maximal solutions of P are defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ and that

$\underset{t\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}(x(t),y(t))=0$

b) Demonstrate that if $(x(0),y(0))\neq(0,0)$ ,

$\forall t\epsilon\mathbb{R}$ :

$(x(t),y(t))\neq(0,0)$

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Thanks for the answer to everyone of you, but the problem is that we haven't studied the Lyapunov Functions yet.. is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: For (a), try finding a Lyapunov function.

Comment: Which tools/ results from ODEs theory do you know? because the first point could be solved using Gronwall's lemma and the second using the uniqueness of the solution, but if you haven't seen them it's not better than using Lyapunov functions

Comment: Yes! both are stuff I know, but I can't connect them.. could you help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: Why two upvotes for a flat PSQ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try out the *Lyapunov Function* : $V(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, so it is :

$$\dot{V}(x,y)=2x(-x+xy)+2y(-2y-x^2)=-2(x^2+2y^2) <0\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2-(0,0)$$

It's also obvious to see that $O(0,0)$ is a stationary point for the system and given the Lyapunov considerations, it's asymptotically stable.

Considering that : $V(x,y) = x^2+y^2 > 0 \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2-(0,0)$ and that it's continuously differentiable, can you figure out if that and the one before leads you somewhere for part $(a)$ **and** part $(b)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Lyapunov functions, the standard one $V=x^2+y^2$ should work.
$$
(\dot Vf)(x,y)=\nabla V\cdot(\dot x,\dot y)^T=2x(-x+xy)+2y(-2y-x^2)=-2(x^2+2y^2)\in[-4V,-2V]
$$

---

Using $v(t)=V(x(t),y(t))$ we thus got
$$
-4v\le \dot v\le -2 v
$$
which can be solved via separation or integrating factor to find
$$
v(0)e^{-4t}\le v(t)\le v(0)e^{-2t}
$$
for $t>0$. The second inequality answers the first question, a bounded solution exists for all times, and the first inequality gives a quantitative answer to the second question.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense this is just a rewriting of the previous answers, but it avoids using explicitly the Lyapunov formalism.

For part a), consider $V(t)=x(t)^2+y(t)^2$. Then
$$ V'(t)= 2x(t)x'(t)+ 2y(t)y'(t) = -2x(t)^2 -4y(t)^2 \leq -2x(t)^2 -2y(t)^2 = -2V(t)$$
In particular, by Gronwall's lemma, we have $V(t)\leq f(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$, where $f$ is the solution of
$$ f(0)=V(0), \quad f'(t)=-2f(t)$$
i.e.
$$ V(t)\leq V(0)e^{-2t} \quad \forall t\geq 0$$
In particular this implies that, for any initial data, the solutions exist for all $t\geq 0$ since the norm $\Vert x(t),y(t)\Vert$ stays bounded (there is no explosion time). Moreover, since $V(t)\geq 0$ and $V(0)e^{-2t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, we also obtain that for any initial data
$$V(t)\to 0 \text{ as } t\to\infty$$

For part b), first of all observe that every term in your ODE is smooth, therefore local existence and uniqueness of the solutons is granted. Moreover, $(0,0)$ is a fixed point, therefore $x(t)=0$, $y(t)=0$ is a solution for the initial data $x(0)=0$, $y(0)=0$ (and by uniqueness it is the only solution).

Now assume that, for some $t$, you have $x(t)=y(t)=0$, i.e. the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ and the solution constantly $0$ "touch" at $t$, then by uniqueness you must have that the two solutions coincide on the domain in which they are both defined, thus $x(0)=y(0)=0$ as well. Therefore, if $(x(0),y(0))\neq(0,0)$, you must have $(x(t),y(t))\ne(0,0)$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out what V is.. Maybe we use another terminology, but what do you mean with "V" ?

Comment: I defined it at the beginning: $V(t)=x(t)^2+y(t)^2=\Vert (x(t),y(t))\Vert^2$, where $(x(t),y(t))$ is the solution to the ODE.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can we say that (0,0) is a fixed point? thanks